# Numerically Solve PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, mathematica

I am looking for some help finding a numerical solution to a pde of the form:

$$C_t=f(x)C_x+\alpha C_{xx}$$

with initial condition for $C(x,t)$:

$$C(x,0)=\delta(x)$$

and boundary condition

$$C(\pm\infty,0)=0$$

I am using Mathematica's NDSolve function, but it doesn't seem to be able to find a solution for some chosen $f(x)$ and $\alpha$. I think this may be due to the condition's at infinity? Another idea I have is to turn it into a ODE via separation of variables. Any advice on resources or methods would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a standard method, like the Crank-Nicolson method, on a truncated spatial domain. The conditions on this artificial boundary can be approximated by  setting the solution to be zero, or some function of $(x,t)$, if some adicional information on the asymptotics is available.

Comment: Yep, works like a charm! Thanks for the guidance.